# Sprite movement stutters a lot randomly

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a sprite and I set its `y` velocity to 200 so that it moves down.

The sprite moves perfectly fine except that sometimes it stutters a lot. The other times it is silky smooth. Its like the fps drops to 20.

**How do I stop this stuttering?**

Below is my code and you can [try it live here](http://chest.vidhucraft.com/PhaserTest/)

```
var SimpleGame = (function () {

    function SimpleGame() {
        this.game = new Phaser.Game(800, 400, Phaser.AUTO, 'content', { preload: this.preload, create: this.create, update: this.update });
    }

    SimpleGame.prototype.preload = function () {
        this.game.load.image('logo', 'Sprites/icon.png');
    };

    SimpleGame.prototype.create = function () {
        //Create Sprite
        this.speed = 133;
        this.game.stage.backgroundColor = 0xffffff;
        this.logo = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY, 'logo');
        this.logo.position.set(200, 50);
        this.game.physics.arcade.enable(this.logo);
        //Set velocity
        this.logo.body.velocity.y = this.speed;
    };

    return SimpleGame;
})();

window.onload = function () {
    var game = new SimpleGame();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting the stuttering myself. So, try loading it with other computers, find friends with different levels of computers, to make sure that it isn't a local client-side problem. If it is, then check your computers firewall settings any antivirus that may be stopping a process which will slow down your game.

If it is a server-side problem- firstly, try to condense your code and the memory used. Use local variables instead of global ones, don't pass too many function arguments (If you are using a lot of function arguments then you are filling up the Stack and that may be causing the lag).

Also check your server. I don't know what web server you are using so I don't really know your specs on this, but I may be able to help. Does Phaser use too much memory for your webserver? Small Webservers are designed purely for small websites so  by using a lot of JS (which Phaser does ,look in Phaser.min!) you may be using too much memory on your server. Maybe a bigger subscription?

I hope I've helped.

Comment: Its not the webserver. Phaser is Javascript which is run on your browser. All of Phaser's memory is in your web browser. Not the server. But thanks for trying to help

Comment: Also thanks for testing it on other computers :) Maybe its just mine